# Expressing $\{\mathbf x: x_n=x_{n+1}\text{ for every $n$ prime number}\}\subseteq R^\omega $ as cross product of subsets of $\mathbb R$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The question is: can we express such a set in terms of cross products between subsets of $\mathbb R$?

We would have $\{\mathbf x=(x_1,x_4,x_4,x_4,x_6,x_6,x_8,x_8,x_9,x_{10},x_{12},x_{12},\dots)\}$. Can we express this set of tuples as $\mathbb R\times\{x_4\}\times\{x_4\}\times\cdots\ {}$?

Of course it's difficult to write this down in a compact or explicit way. I appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that $(0,1,1,1,\dots)\in\{\mathbf x: x_n=x_{n+1}\text{ for every $n$ prime number}\}$ and $(0,2,2,2,\dots)\in\{\mathbf x: x_n=x_{n+1}\text{ for every $n$ prime number}\}$. Then the second subset of $\mathbb R$ from which the $x_2$ is picked would contain at least $1$ and $2$. The same would happen with the third and fourth subsets of $\mathbb R$. This leads to $(0,1,2,1,\dots)\in\{\mathbf x: x_n=x_{n+1}\text{ for every $n$ prime number}\}$, which is a contradiction.